# How to safely configure/use SW RAID 5 with Raspberry PI 4b / DietPi without data loss?

Tags: raspberry-pi, rsync, software-raid, raid-5

This question is also to clarify if I have a decent bug here, software or hardware. My aim is to set up a SW-RAID-5 to my Raspberry PI 4b system using a USB3.0 HUB with 3 4 TB Western Digital hard disk drives. Problems have been occured during configuration (recovering) and / or during rsyncing data to it.
My scope: I am new to the topic using (SW) RAID and Raspberry PI, but have been using Debian (UBUNTU) for probably 12 years as a user and Java programmer.

Till now all my efforts turned to superblock errors on 1, 2 or all 3 disks. I was then not able to recover the array and it constantly comes up with "Input/Output errors".

My configuration:

- Raspberry PI 4b
- 3 4 TB hard disk drives WD RedOne NAS series
- 4x USB 3.0 Hub connected to the raspberry PI and the hard drives
- DietPi as recommended OS

My steps so far:

- Install mdadm connect via ssh (or command line shell via keyboard and
  monitor)
- doing smartmonctl short and long test to make sure the hard    drives
  have no damage (cause transportation via amazon seems most of    the
  time like bingo regarding packaging), resulting in 0 errors as    far
  as I can judge that
- Following almost this tutorial:
  https://canox.net/2016/06/die-eigene-cloud-mit-dem-raspberry-pi-und-nextcloud/

This means I have spent quiet some times doing these basic steps, logged in as a root user, /dev/sd[abc] is just an initial startup situation, which can obviously change, when plugging in and out and adding new hard drives or removing them:

```
$ mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=3 /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc
[$ mdadm --detail --scan >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf]
[$ mount /dev/md0 /nextCloud]
```

Step 2 and 3 were only optional and not part of my last trials to just get the array started (or initialised/recovered)

It took me time to recognise that the following recovering part is essential for creating the system and will take ages to finish. Although I found advice that writing to the RAID array during this "recovery" should be ok so I first tried to put my backed up data to it:

I mounted on the other USB 3.0 port my back up hard drive (1.8TB) to /usbmount:

```
$ cd /usbmount
$ rsync -a --info=progress2 video music private photo public /nextCloud
```

This was during the "recovery" and ended shortly after starting in a set of "input/output" errors, making the array inusable. Before I was able for example to make a directory on the array, but after the rsync command it fails with "superblock errors" on some or all drives.

I remember using

```
$ mdadm -D /dev/md0
```

resulting in something like (output derived and manually changed now from my UBUNTU work station according to my memory) on the very first trial of doing this:

```
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Tue Aug 27 00:27:01 2019
     Raid Level : raid5
     Array Size : 7813774336 (7451.80 GiB 8001.30 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906887168 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
   Raid Devices : 3
  Total Devices : 3
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

  Intent Bitmap : Internal

    Update Time : Tue Aug 27 09:08:34 2019
          State : clean, degraded, recovering 
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 3
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 1

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

 Rebuild Status : 0.1% complete

           Name : laptoppete-G752VSK:0  (local to host laptoppete-G752VSK)
           UUID : d978dd44:93a147bb:4ce5f283:a7a1a3c1
         Events : 5110
    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       -       -       -        0      -
       -       -       -        1      -
       -       -       -        2      -

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       48        0      spare part : /dev/sdd
       1       8       64        1      active sync   /dev/sde
       3       8       80        2      spare rebuilding   /dev/sdf
```

I tried to repair it by:

- Stopping mdadm
- Zeroing superblock failed anyway

I was only able to access my data array again by thoroughly destroying it/reformatting it on my Ubuntu 16.04 working station.

Then replug to the RaspberryPi/DietPi system and after doing above first step, I ran into this issue by not copying, but just waiting for the 24 hrs recovering trail. After about I guess 40% was recovered it turned to have the same issue. I was trying meanwhile rsyncing to another device (a 32 GB stick), which I only used for testing if something is wrong with my rsyncing (I tried rsync also with --info=progress2 and alternatively --progress flag). I am not sure, but I think it failed during the last call.

Then again all (!) mounts were broken and all connected hard drives issued a broken superblock and "Input/ouput" errors. Again it was not possible to access the array or the other mounted hard disk drives until first unplug/reformat on other system and rebooting.

Now I kindly ask you. Do I do a systematic error here? Or do I have a severe DietPi DeepShit I/O problem or even a hardware failure? I appreciate any useful help here! Thanks in advance!

[EDIT] I did all steps on an UBUNTU 16.04, which at least recovers much faster, but also failed in accessing the array, especially after unplugging/replugging (tried to connect with this link on my target RaspberryPI system):
https://serverfault.com/questions/32709/how-do-i-move-a-linux-software-raid-to-a-new-machine

Any tips how to **exclude configuration errors, hardware issues with the drives or the hub or the raspberry pi, or any related Linux OS or tools issues** regarding mdadm or rsync are very welcome!

Comment: A RAID5 array of 4tb disks on a Pi is not a good idea. The risk of unrecoverable failure of a  RAID5 array on disks> 2 tb makes RAID5 not fit for purpose. Doing the required calculation and IO on a Pi means you can't even get useful speed out of it.

Comment: Ok, but it is the Raspberry Pi 4b with full USB3.0 assistance, so I thought, It might be ok for speed.
According to reliance That is a good hint! But why is that not reliable enough? Are there any good advisors on the market, which I until now did not find??

Comment: Ok I saw your comment here: [https://superuser.com/questions/1205789/big-linux-software-raid-using-usb-disks].

Comment: @davidgo: Thank you for your hints! 
Maybe I will head then for a non-RAID system and use a second hard drive for a weekly backup via rsync...RAID 10 is definetely too much for my PI. 

Plus I have seen now enough problems recurring doing it on my G752 Ubuntu laptop and my PI. Both the same problems and constantly destroying the superblocks while finishing a second ago. Rsync causes reliably that problems, Deplugging as well as sometimes mounting (at least the second time after reboot)

Answer (score 0):

As @davidgo pointed out above and further on in this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1205789/big-linux-software-raid-using-usb-disks#answer-1205803), it is not a good idea to use a software RAID on a PI. Escpecially a RAID-5, which was for me at first the best choice between data redundancy, probability of fault and price.

But following more simple tutorials (which have the same working steps in general), showed many problems as described in the question. Even on a Ubuntu, the new recovered RAID-5 system went faulty after reboot. Another sure way to a system failure was done by simply copying with "rsync -a".

As I want a more reliable system, I head now for a different solution. Maybe a backed up own/nextCloud system, where I simply add data safety by backing up once a week (manually by a script and a only for this purpose turned on USB drive, i.e. my second drive from above's configuration).

If nobody wants to add something here, I would let this answer here as a recommendation not to do a software RAID connected by a USB3 hub. Do a hardware based raid, do something directly on the system bus, but not via USB3.0. If I did not a severe mistake it is simply not reliable and robust.

The risk of a permanent data loss is big IMHO, not only in terms of probability as pointed out above in the link and in the link of [ZDNET](http://zdnet.com/article/why-raid-5-stops-working-in-2009) (in the comments below), but in terms of unsafetyness of the process itself (lying not yet analysed somewhere between USB 3.0 HUB and OS system and the tool managing RAID: mdadm).

Comment: There is another element to consider - most external drives comprise low power "green" drives (in WD case actually green, but low performance, low power) subtly crippled to not to work well with RAID - There is an idea of TLR (time limited recovery) which is important in RAID but not generally.  Using Owncloud is probably a better idea then RAID in your case. Also, look at rsnapshot for your secondary backup if your data is fairly static. (It uses symlinks to save space and do point in time recovery and backup)

Comment: Also https://www.zdnet.com/article/why-raid-5-stops-working-in-2009/ has a simplified explanation why RAID5 is no good with large disks.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look on snapshot, @davidgo !

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the Interesting fact of TLER working contradictory to the RAID system, supposingly causing annoying extra trouble! So good features do not work well together, amplifying themselves to a malfunction.
I am such a noob!

Comment: Thanks, also for the background article on ZDNET  :-). If I had been only aware of the risks before buying crappy hard drives to reduce my failure risk (which I wanted to do coming from an unbackupped solution with a single drive (reporting all the time good health till its sudden death on a sunny sunday afternoon...))